# Returning multiple values based on sentence.

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can someone help me modify this sheet that is designed to show me how many invalid words have been used in a single string (A3).

I have an index match (never done one before) to return when one of those words is used. How ever I would like this to work to look across the entire column span of I:AH and to return all the triggered words into B7:B20.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3dhFtJhzxgi_uaaRh4A_w5IHZvmwXh20G3OFEqkAgs/edit?usp=sharing

Can you help?

Comment: Welcome at superuser. Questions should be self containing here. Please include relevant screenshot / data instead of referring to external file.

Comment: Sorry. Didnt know.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/n6l194c7d/